# Best method to store form values WITHOUT sending them to a MySQL Database for Payment Gateway Processing

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been scratching my head for days now and wonder if you can help.

I am busy developing a ticket booking system BUT don’t want to store data to the database UNTIL payment successful, or in other words the visitor is returned to my site after payment.

So what I have is a form that a post to a confirmation form. On the confirmation form I catch all the values via POST commands for visitor to review. I then POST this off to the payment provider and once the transaction is successful the visitor is routed back to my site with a confirmation page.

It’s THIS confirmation page that I want to use the store the values in the mysql database.

Now I can use sessions to keep the values in an array or I could write the values into a TEMP database table, but I don’t want to write to and back from the database to many times as I don’t have load balancing in place plus I want to it to be as lightweight as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have actually answered your own question with the bit about storing the data in a session :)

Comment: A combination of session and database could be made, but it all depends on how reliable and consistent the system as a whole should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple. Important data have to be stored in a **reliable** storage. Session is not one by design.
So, being guided by not a whim but a reason, you'll end up storing this data in database, connecting it with user id.

Comment: To add, if a session cookie is lost, the storage can be very reliable but you still lose data :) tying data to an account is a better idea (tm)

Answer (score -1):

The solution, as you said, is to use SESSION. If you want data to be more persistent, you can also use cookies.

So before sending your data to the payment gateway, you should do something like this :

```
$_SESSION['posted_data'] = $_POST;
```

Comment: use cookies for payment details, why, thank you I've just paid 10000$ in goods, please ship them asap.

Comment: You can encode an id into your cookie that will be the one sent back from the payment gateway. So, if there is no correlation between the two, you know that the data are corrupted. Everything depands on which kind of data he wants to store.

Comment: definitely. But often if somebody asks here is a novice, and I prefer to err on the side of caution rather on a clever design idea (note, the -1 isn't mine)